# Mapbox react native can't load styles

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to add a Mapbox map ti my iOS app and I only get a black screen ; xCode outputs [ERROR] {Map}[Setup]: loading style failed: no such file or directory
I've tried with all of these :

```
styleURL={'asset://styles/dark-v8.json'}
styleURL={'asset://styles/emerald-v8.json'}
styleURL={'asset://styles/light-v8.json'}
```

Where are the styles supposed to be ? I believe I forgot to add something to my project...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the latest version, styles aren't bundled locally anymore with the framework. Try something like `mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v8.json` (for Mapbox-hosted styles, it's `mapbox://styles/<user>/<style>`).

Comment: OK, thanks, works with a Mapbox-hosted style but not with the "default" ones (light, dark or emerald)

Comment: how can i add locally?

Comment: For future reference, you can use: `styleJSON` as a parameter in `Mapview`